# How to Create multiple word documents(blank) thru excel macro, with specific name?

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I have a 2 columns in a excel sheet, one having directory and another one having Requirement name.What I want is that macro should create Word Document for each value of 2nd column, with the name of the Requirement AND in the directory mentioned in 1st coulmn.
**(And it should automatially create directories if they are not available)**

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: Since you are dealing with multiple applications the macro recorder will not be of much use to you, but this is not a terribly difficult exercise. Please show what you have tried so far and we can assist.

Answer (score 0):

I've quickly whipped this up, which opens your word document, saves it based on the directory in `Range("A2")`, with the filename in `Range("B2")`, and then closes the file.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim oWord As Word.Application
Set oWord = New Word.Application
oWord.Visible = True

oWord.Documents.Add Template:="Normal", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0
oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=Range("A2") & Range("B2")
oWord.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=False

oWord.Quit
Set oWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

This should provide you with a good basis for cycling through your A column, and save the documents, and then correcting any empty directories (can be done with an if statement).

You will have to ensure that you have the Microsoft Word Reference checked - to do this, ensure you're in the VBA screen, click on "Tools" > "References" and then find "Microsoft Word xx.0 Object Library" in the list. Note; xx.0 will be specific to the version of Word you're running.

Hope this helps you to get started!